# How to extract Table from a Citrix Environment using Automation Anywhere?

Tags: automation, citrix, rpa, automationanywhere

I am new to Automation Anywhere (RPA Tool). I need to extract a table (information) from a Citrix Environment. Does somebody have any experience regarding this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Automation Anywhere does not have great capability in this area. Citrix places a layer over the tables you're wanting to interact with. That's their whole security thing.

UiPath does have a new concept that allows it to emulate what it thinks is behind Citrix. This is cutting edge and sometimes unpredictable. Automation Anywhere does not have this yet, but they probably will soon. If it's an option - I recommend testing out the development version of UiPath. You can read more about their Citrix Automation technology here - https://www.uipath.com/solutions/technology/citrix-automation

For now, it's my understanding that the best you can do is create and build out OCR and Image Recognition in AA to replicate that technology. So you would have a lot more lines of code. That's all UiPath is doing anyways.

Answer (score -1):

If AA tool is installed inside citrix environment then it's easy to extract table using web recorder if the table is web based. In web recorder we have direct option as extract table.
If it is windows based, you can go ahead with Object cloning or Manage windows control

Comment: That is obvious but what if we are not allowed to install AA inside citrix env. I mean we wanna achieve the goal working in citrix env.